# How to use android room in aar library?

Tags: android, android-room

I have a main app project and a library project. They all need to use the room. For example: an app project has a student entity, a library project has a book entity. What should I do to use only one RoomDatabase?(because the room register entity in RetentionPolicy.CLASS)

The other database can register an entity in runtime so I can just dynamically add it. Each project just need to extend a base database.

Comment: The situation is my app project is so big that I have to split it to different sub projects, each sub project will use db, so I want to each projects to extend a same base database, but hold the entities itself

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using one database just create two tables in the same database.
Below is the code sample that illustrates how to achieve it.

```
@Database(
    entities = {
        Student.class,
        Book.class
    },
    version = VERSION
```

)

Comment: I know this. The main problem is how to use the same database in two different project. Because room is base on annotation, I can't extend a base database in two difference project.

Comment: Why would you want to extend it? Because it's just a model class which can be rewritten

Comment: My app project is so big that I have to split it to different sub projects, each sub project will use db, so I want to each projects to extend a same base database, but hold the entities itself

Comment: If you hold the entities in another module then your database module will be dependent on the module which needs to access it and now the problem arises because `Module A` is dependent on `Database Module` and now to use the entities you will make the `Database Module` dependent on the `Module A` so this will lead to the circular dependncy.

Comment: It's better to have your entities in the `Database Module` and you can use packages to organize those entities.

Comment: Yeah,that is the key problems. The room Database dependent on Entity. I have to put all entities with Database.

Comment: Yes , if my answer is helpful kindly mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the solution for this question.